# mysql - Why do we need RDS when we can use docker image for mysql

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, docker

From my understanding, Aws RDS facilitate backup for the mysql database, but it is not cheap.

While using docker image for mysql may save us more in terms of cost? Because we only need to download the docker image for dockerhub and directly use it for free(e.g. create an instance and run the container).

Is there another reason of using RDS other than facilitating backup for the database?

Comment: Do you have specific a use-case in mind? The question is similar to: "why should I use AWS at all if I can host my application on RPi at home/work". You don't need to user RDS if mysql in docker suits your needs.

Comment: I just wonder in what use case I should use RDS and what use case I shouldn't

Comment: RDS is something you just click a button and it works. Docker containers require a lot more effort. You can back up a container if you add in other support containers or set up your container(s) in a specific way, but this a lot more custom.

Comment: How is it going with the issue? Is it still unclear why RDS could be better then mysql in docker?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I list several features of RDS which may warrant using it over **self-managed** MySQL docker container on an EC2 insistence or ECS:

- RDS is **managed service**, so all OS updates, MySQL patches are managed by AWS and you don't have to worry about them.
- RDS supports **storage auto-scaling** - you can start with small db, and RDS will extend storage automatically as needed.
- **Point-in-time** recovery allowing you to "rewind" your recent db changes.
- **Read replicas** - you can create up to 5 read replicas of your database to off-load read intensive applications from your primary db instance.
- **Cross-region** read replica - you can have your replica in different region which is good for disaster recovery (entire AWS region goes down)
- Automated and manual **backups**, including backups to a different region.
- **IAM** authentication to your db instead of regular username/password.
- **Multi-AZ** - RDS can keep a stand-by replica of your primary database instance in different availability zone, for quick recovery if it fails.
- CloudWatch integrated **db metrics and logs**.
- **RDS event notifications** allow you for straight-forward  development of automations e.g. invoke lambda automatically for every backup, or if something fails.
- Easier **integration** with other services, e.g. use of RDS Proxy in Lambda functions.

All these and other features of RDS make it much more expensive then hosting a self-managed MySQL docker container. But if MySQL in docker container meets all your requirements, then there is no need to use RDS. You can always start with the docker, and if your data and requirements grow, you can migrate to RDS.